# Magento 2 sales_order_place_before product items

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have an observer that is retrieving the order in the event: sales_order_place_before

however I need to get the data of the products of that order, and in my data, nothing comes about the product, it comes like this (I'll put it below), is there how I can retrieve the data of the products of that order?

```
{
   "applied_rule_ids":"",
   "base_currency_code":"BRL",
   "base_discount_amount":0,
   "base_grand_total":19.9,
   "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
   "base_shipping_amount":0,
   "base_shipping_discount_amount":0,
   "base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt":0,
   "base_shipping_incl_tax":0,
   "base_shipping_tax_amount":0,
   "base_subtotal":19.9,
   "base_subtotal_incl_tax":19.9,
   "base_tax_amount":0,
   "base_total_due":19.9,
   "base_to_global_rate":1,
   "base_to_order_rate":1,
   "customer_email":"customer@gmail.com",
   "customer_firstname":"Customer",
   "customer_group_id":1,
   "customer_id":"3",
   "customer_is_guest":0,
   "customer_lastname":"Rodrigues",
   "customer_note_notify":1,
   "customer_taxvat":"00000000000",
   "discount_amount":0,
   "discount_description":"",
   "global_currency_code":"BRL",
   "grand_total":19.9,
   "discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
   "increment_id":"000000102",
   "is_virtual":1,
   "order_currency_code":"BRL",
   "quote_id":"85",
   "remote_ip":"127.0.0.1",
   "shipping_amount":0,
   "shipping_discount_amount":0,
   "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
   "shipping_incl_tax":0,
   "shipping_tax_amount":0,
   "store_currency_code":"BRL",
   "store_id":1,
   "store_to_base_rate":0,
   "store_to_order_rate":0,
   "subtotal":19.9,
   "subtotal_incl_tax":19.9,
   "tax_amount":0,
   "total_due":19.9,
   "total_qty_ordered":1,
   "weight":0,
   "items":[
      {
         
      }
   ],
   "status_histories":[
      
   ],
   "extension_attributes":{
      
   },
   "addresses":[
      {
         
      }
   ],
   "payment":{
      
   },
   "customer_middlename":null,
   "customer_person_type":null,
   "customer_social_name":null,
   "customer_business_name":null,
   "customer_state_registration":null,
   "gift_cards":"[]",
   "gift_cards_amount":0,
   "base_gift_cards_amount":0,
   "gw_id":null,
   "gw_allow_gift_receipt":null,
   "gw_add_card":null,
   "gw_price":false,
   "gw_base_price":false,
   "gw_items_price":false,
   "gw_items_base_price":false,
   "gw_card_price":false,
   "gw_card_base_price":false,
   "gw_base_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_items_base_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_items_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_card_base_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_card_tax_amount":null,
   "gw_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gw_base_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gw_items_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gw_items_base_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gw_card_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gw_card_base_price_incl_tax":null,
   "gift_message_id":null,
   "state":"new",
   "status":"pending"
}
```

is it possible for me to recover the product data? or is there any other event that happens before payment for me to use, that comes with the product data?

Comment: Please load current quote instead of order

Comment: how would i do it? @GohilRajesh

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. just call $order->getAllItems() to get order item data.

```
class OrderPlaceBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{


    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $payment = $order->getPayment(); // get payment object from order object
        $paymentMethod = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode(); // get payment method
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($item->getProductId());
            $product->getSku();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, there is nothing in $order->getAllItems()

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution

```
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $order->save();
 $order->getId();
```

and now i have all the order data